# Binding method with multiple arguments to <<ListboxSelect>>

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to make a method execute on the selection of an item in a tkinter listbox. I can bind some function to is using `.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", method)`, but if i try to give any arguments to it, like `method(argumentone, argumenttwo)`, the method no longer executes on the selection of an item from the listbox. It is however executed at startup when Mainloop starts. Furthermore, giving arguments to a method is problematic, as i cant pass the event argument already passed to any bound method, as it is not assigned to any variable beforehand. I'd like to be able to pass the event and one other variable to some method ideally. Any help on achieving this would be very welcome. Some example code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
def onSelection(event, foo):
    widget = event.widget
    print(widget.curselection())
    print(foo)


sam = "sam"
chars = Listbox(main)
chars.insert(someList)
chars.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", onSelection(evt, sam))
```

Note that this code doesn't work. evt isn't defined.

Comment: There are many questions and answers on this site related to passing arguments with bind. Have you read through any of them?

Comment: Yeah, i've read all that i can. Either they don't work, or dont pass arguments other than the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a function in `bind()` that ends in parenthesis it just runs the function without bind generating an event. Instead you have to give bind a name. You can accomplish this with `lambda` or `functools.partial`. I'll use lambda in my example.

Bind is generating an event when triggered, so lambda will have to take it as input. Then call `onSelection()` with desired arguments.

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

def onSelection(event, foo):
    widget = event.widget
    print(widget.curselection())
    print(foo)

someList = ['Stilton', 'Brie', 'Edam', 'Cheddar', 'Ilchester']

chars = Listbox(main)
chars.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
for item in someList:
    chars.insert("end", item)

sam = "sam"
chars.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda event: onSelection(event, sam))
# Take care of event created by bind ----^                    ^
# Pass the event as well as argument to callback function ----|

main.mainloop()
```